# XSS alert not working with concatenated string

Tags: penetration-test, xss, javascript, html

I've noticed that the following Stored XSS does not execute, whereas in the JS console it works:

```
<img src=0 onerror=alert(document.domain+": "+Date.now())>
```

This doesn't prompt an alert box. Whereas the following do:

```
<img src=0 onerror=alert(Date.now())>
<img src=0 onerror=alert(document.domain)>
```

Casting any of the elements with `String()` doesn't help either.

The plain alert statement (`alert(document.domain+": "+Date.now())`) works in the Chrome JS console, in Firefox it works if I add the semicolon at the end.

I'm certainly no JS wizard, but I don't see why this doesn't work.

Why does the initial XSS via the image tag not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove space in `": "` or add quotes for onerror attribute value:

```
<img src=0 onerror='alert(document.domain+": "+Date.now())'>
```

Comment: To encode the space, you can use `":\x20"`.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You put a quote in the original one. This messes up the HTML parser because `"` has special meaning inside the attribute space of a tag.</strike>

I'm wrong. It's the space.

Comment: So I assume this `<img src=0 onerror=alert(document.domain+': '+Date.now())>` should work? I just tested it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I think that's actually not because of the quote but the space. Quotes inside an unquoted attribute AFAIK don't bother the parser.

Comment: @Arminius Interesting! Without the space it works - why is that so?

Comment: @GarlicCheese Because if your attribute value is unquoted, the parser assumes that after a space a new attribute is starting.

Comment: @Arminius I'm afraid I don't follow. What attribute is unquoted? How can I use spaces in this scenario?

Comment: @GarlicCheese In `<a b=c d='e' f="g">`, b, d and f are an unquoted, a single-quoted and a double-quoted attribute, respectively.

Comment: @Arminius Gotcha! Thanks a lot. `<img src=0 onerror="alert(document.domain+': '+Date.now())">` works. If you want to form a an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @Arminius You are correct. Whoops!